# C++ OOP Classes and Constructors

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

Pretty new to C++ here and programming as a whole so please be patient and understanding that my explanations may not be on the mark.  The assignment for my OOP class calls for the following:

Design an Inventory class that can hold information for an item in a retail store's inventory.
Required private member variables:
 - item number
 - quantity
 - cost
Required public member functions

Default constructor - Sets all the member variables to 0
Constructor #2 - Accepts an item's number, quantity and cost as arguments.  Calls other class functions to copy these values into the appropriate member variables.

They way I'm going about this is slightly different.  Rather than 1 value I'm trying to initialize an array and store all the values enter by the user there.  However it seems, once the user exits the member/class function the value is removed from the array.

Kind of at my wits end here so any info or recommendations would greatly help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class inventory
{
    private:
        int productNum[10];
        int productCount[10];
        double productPrice[10];
        int inventoryFillLevel;
        int userPNumber;
        int userQuantity;
        double userPrice;
    public:
        inventory()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            userPNumber = 0;
            userQuantity = 0;
            userPrice = 0;
            while (counter < 10)
            {
                productNum[counter] = 5;
                productCount[counter] = 6;
                productPrice[counter] = 7;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        inventory(int pNumber, int pCount, int pPrice)
        {
            cout << "Now we're in the 2nd constructor in the Class" << endl;
            cout << "The 1st number entered by the user is: " << pNumber << endl;
            cout << "The 2nd number entered by the user is: " << pCount << endl;
            cout << "The 3rd number entered by the user is: " << pPrice << endl;
            Input(pNumber);
        }
        void Input(int pNumber)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            cout << "\nNow we're in the function as called by the Constructor." << endl;
            cout << "The 1st number entered by the user is: " << pNumber << endl;
            cout << "In the function the counter is: " << counter << endl;
            cout << "The value in the array at " << counter << " is: " << productNum[counter] << endl;
            cout << "Now we set that to the value entered by the user" << endl;
            productNum[counter] = pNumber;
            cout << "And now the value in the array is: " << productNum[counter] << endl;
        }
         void Show()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            cout << "After entering the value, let's check what is stored in the array: ";
            cout << productNum[counter] << endl;
        }
};

 int main()
{

    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;

    inventory inv1;

    cout << "1st User entered value" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "2nd User entered value" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "3rd User entered value" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Now we call the 2nd constructor and pass the values to it" << endl;
    inventory(a, b, c);

    inv1.Show();    

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks again for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value are not getting removed. There is small flaw in the code.

1)- You are making mistake while creating an object. You are calling `Show` method with object created by default constructor.

```
inventory inv1;

....
inv1.Show();
```

Change the declaration of `inv1`  to `inventory inv1(a, b, c);` and call then call show method.

Also `inventory(a, b, c);` will create new object and will not effect `inv1`.

2)- You are always storing values at index `0` of the member array. 
As you are declaring `int counter = 0` whenever you are calling any method/constructor.

Make `int counter ;` a class member.

```
class inventory
{
    private:
        int counter;
    public:
       inventory():counter(0){....}

    ....
};
```

It will count the items you already push in your inventory.
Though you will have to take care how many item you already pushed in.
Alternative approach can be you can use `std::vector` instead of `int array` .

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be handling your class incorrectly. The line

```
inventory(a, b, c);
```

only creates a temporary instance of `inventory` that is gone essentially after the line finishes execution. So when you call `inv1.Show()` it's still using the values that are assigned in your default constructor when `inv1` was declared. You should remove the current declaration of `inv` and change

```
inventory(a, b, c);
```

to

```
inventory inv1(a, b, c);
```

Comment: I thought that's what was going on.  I think what it boils down to is my understanding of the intent of constructors. I'm looking to have one initialize an array and all values with 0 and then call another to constructor to fill the same array with data, which apparently is not what they do.  In this scenario they should be seen as giving the user 2 options.  Either create an empty array object or create and fill an array?  Is that on more on point?